# Using GROUP BY on a Dataset in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datatable

This should be simple but it's not working as intended

I have a flat text file that is imported to a Dataset table, I just need to count occurences of a UserDefined3 column so in SQL it would be

SELECT UserDefined3, COUNT(UserDefined3)
FROM MRDF
GROUP BY UserDefined3

but I'm not sure how to do this in VB.NET acting on a DataTable

Comment: There is very limited ability built into `DataTables` to query the data they contain and it doesn't include a query like that. You would have to use LINQ. If you're not already familiar with LINQ then you need to research the topic first, do what you can and then show what you've done if it doesn't work.